# How to break text to a new line when space occurs between words for an svg document

Tags: svg

I have an svg text element that looks like this :

`<text class="new" x="22%" y="80%" style="dominant-baseline:central; display:table-caption; text-anchor:middle; font-size:25px; fill:#E3E3E4; font-family:'MyriadPro-Regular'">Random heading
</text>`

I added a class new to the text element but however much I try, I can get the text to break where space occurs in the text. I know how to do this when not working with an SVG document. I just can't seem to understand why it won't work.

The text remains as is. I want to split it so that the word breaks where space occurs. In our case, I need the output to be:

Random 
heading

I have tried the following:
word-break, display:table-caption

I don't wish to use fixed width because I want to use the space for defining where the text breaks to a new line. Please help if you know of a solution.

Comment: SVG does not natively support word wrapping.

Comment: Is it possible to add html element and use that to manipulate using CSS?

Comment: Sure, use foreignObject to wrap the HTML.